# Multilined commenting in vim using /** ... */

Tags: comments, vim

Note: When I'm describing /** ... */ comment blocks, I'm referring to the following types of comment blocks

```
/**
 * This is a comment block that
 * spans multiple lines.
 *
 * Each line is prefixed with a "\t* " string
 */
```

I'm used to the very automated commenting of comment blocks in IDEs, but it doesn't seem that vim supports these kinds of comments too well.

Specifically, I'm looking for this kind of automated functionality. Say you have the following comment

```
/**
 * This is a comment and I plan to run to the next line.
```

In vim's insert mode, when my cursor is at the period and I hit "enter", I want another "\t* " string to be placed on the new line.

Furthermore, when I hit "/" to end the comment block on a brand new line starting with "\t* ", it would delete the space and place "/" on this new line.

For example, if I have

```
/**
 * This is a comment and I plan to run to the next line.
 *
```

(with a space after the '*' character), and I hit "/", I should produce

```
/**
 * This is a comment and I plan to run to the next line.
 */
```

Any plug in or vimscript that would help me support this?

Note that I've looked at the nerd commenter already, but the comments created by the nerd commenter don't seem automated (ie: I have to press a keystroke or two to activate commenting.)

Also, whenever I make block comments, I always start with "/**".

Comment: I feel like vim does this already. (Or at least mine does with `ft=java`)

Comment: Yea, vim does this already for me too when the filetype is java

Comment: How would I have VIM do the same thing when the file type is C#?

Also, I just tried creating block comments in vim with a java file, and it didn't work for me.

Comment: @hlin117 I assume you have `filetype plugin indent on` somewhere in your vimrc?

Comment: No I didn't. I just put it in, and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim can do this by itself. Just add

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

to your vimrc.

---

After this is done the defualt ftplugins should enable it for you. If it doesn't I believe adding to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`

```
setlocal formatoptions+=r
```

should enable it.

Comment: Such a long question. Yet such a short answer.

Comment: So, this works for a java and C++ file. But how can I set vim to do the same thing for C# (.cs) files?

Comment: @hlin117 Mine do that for c# too. I think the relevant options is `set formatoptions+=r` (it should default to something like `formatoptions=croql in c sharp files)

Comment: The `'formatoption'` option is local to a buffer. If the default values for a specific filetype are not what you want then set the values then you can do something like: add `setlocal formatoptions=croql` to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`